# How to remove this loop to call div elements separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

**Here's the code I'm using for the audio players:**

https://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/ZbxYYG

**What it does:**

Creates multiple audio players at once (by using a single div element) for each song using a loop.

***Loop:***

```
/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in files */
function createAudioElements() {
    for (f in files) {
        var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";
        $("#audio-players").append(audioString);
    }
}

/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in files */
function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}
```

***var files:***

```
var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
            "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
            "interlude.mp3", // 2
            "scriptures.mp3" // 3
            ];
```

***Is invoked in HTML when I use:***

```
<div id="audio-players"></div>
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

Remove the loop so I could insert any player **separately** and **tweak them separately** however I want like this: https://puu.sh/ynD4q/6ab2ba7816.png

I want to use this code to invoke the desired audio player:

```
<audio id="audio-0" class="audio" preload="true">
    <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer-0" class="audioplayer">
    <button id="playbutton-0" class="play playbutton"></button>
    <div id="timeline-0" class="timeline">
        <div id="playhead-0" class="playhead"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to use it, the play / stop / change position buttons stop working.

It's driving me crazy, I just started learning jQuery. **Thank you a lot!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `files` array to the `settings` object and add object for each of the files with `elementId` and `src` properties:

```
var settings = [
    {"elementId" : "audio-player-1", "src" : "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3"},
    {"elementId" : "audio-player-2", "src" : "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/chooseyourweapon.mp3"},
    {"elementId" : "audio-player-3", "src" : "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/scriptures.mp3"}
];
```

It's very usable, because you can add any property you want. And with `src` attribute you can add audio files from any website that allows it.

Then in `createAudioElements` set new `src` attribute to `settings[f].src`.

Afterwards in `createAudioElements` and `createAudioPlayers` functions change the selector name (to which the rows gathered in the loop are added) to the dynamically generated from the relevant `elementId` property `$("#" + files[f].elementId)`.

```js
// Event listener for DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDOMHasLoaded, false);

// array of audio files (stored in a folder called music)
var settings = [{
    "elementId": "audio-player-1",
    "src": "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3"
  },
  {
    "elementId": "audio-player-2",
    "src": "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/chooseyourweapon.mp3"
  },
  {
    "elementId": "audio-player-3",
    "src": "http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/scriptures.mp3"
  }
];

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Find and store audio info
///////////////////////////////////////////////

// array for AudioObjects
var audioList = [];
// components and the index for their AudioObject
var componentDict = {};
// store AudioObject that is currently playing
var playingAudio = null;
// store playhead id if one is being dragged
var onplayhead = null;

/* AudioObject Constructor */
function AudioObject(audio, duration) {
  this.audio = audio;
  this.id = audio.id;
  this.duration = duration;
}
/* bindAudioPlayer
 * Store audioplayer components in correct AudioObject
 * num identifes correct audioplayer
 */
AudioObject.prototype.bindAudioPlayer = function(num) {
  this.audioplayer = document.getElementById("audioplayer-" + num);
  this.playbutton = document.getElementById("playbutton-" + num);
  this.timeline = document.getElementById("timeline-" + num);
  this.playhead = document.getElementById("playhead-" + num);
  this.timelineWidth = this.timeline.offsetWidth - this.playhead.offsetWidth
}

/* addEventListeners() */
AudioObject.prototype.addEventListeners = function() {
  this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  this.audio.addEventListener("durationchange", AudioObject.prototype.durationChange, false);
  this.timeline.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick, false);
  this.playbutton.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay, false);
  // Makes playhead draggable
  this.playhead.addEventListener('mousedown', AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

/* populateAudioList */
function populateAudioList() {
  var audioElements = document.getElementsByClassName("audio");
  for (i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++) {
    audioList.push(
      new AudioObject(audioElements[i], 0)
    );
    audioList[i].bindAudioPlayer(i);
    audioList[i].addEventListeners();
  }
}

/* populateComponentDictionary()
 * {key=element id : value=index of audioList} */
function populateComponentDictionary() {
  for (i = 0; i < audioList.length; i++) {
    componentDict[audioList[i].audio.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playbutton.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].timeline.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playhead.id] = i;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Update Audio Player
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* durationChange
 * set duration for AudioObject */
AudioObject.prototype.durationChange = function() {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.duration = this.duration;
}

/* pressPlay()
 * call play() for correct AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay = function() {
  var index = getAudioListIndex(this.id);
  audioList[index].play();
}

/* play()
 * play or pause selected audio, if there is a song playing pause it
 */
AudioObject.prototype.play = function() {
  if (this == playingAudio) {
    playingAudio = null;
    this.audio.pause();
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton play");
  }
  // else check if playing audio exists and pause it, then start this
  else {
    if (playingAudio != null) {
      playingAudio.audio.pause();
      changeClass(playingAudio.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    }
    this.audio.play();
    playingAudio = this;
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton pause");
  }
}

/* timelineClick()
 * get timeline's AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick = function(event) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(event, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
}

/* mouseDown */
AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
  onplayhead = this.id;
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
  ao.audio.removeEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
}

/* mouseUp EventListener
 * getting input from all mouse clicks */
function mouseUp(e) {
  if (onplayhead != null) {
    var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
    // change current time
    ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(e, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
    ao.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  }
  onplayhead = null;
}

/* mousemove EventListener
 * Moves playhead as user drags */
AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead = function(e) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
  var newMargLeft = e.clientX - getPosition(ao.timeline);

  if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= ao.timelineWidth) {
    document.getElementById(onplayhead).style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft < 0) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft > ao.timelineWidth) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = ao.timelineWidth + "px";
  }
}

/* timeUpdate
 * Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio
 * this is the html audio element
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate = function() {
  // audio element's AudioObject
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  var playPercent = ao.timelineWidth * (ao.audio.currentTime / ao.duration);
  ao.playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
  // If song is over
  if (ao.audio.currentTime == ao.duration) {
    changeClass(ao.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    ao.audio.currentTime = 0;
    ao.audio.pause();
    playingAudio = null;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Utility Methods
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* changeClass
 * overwrites element's class names */
function changeClass(element, newClasses) {
  element.className = newClasses;
}

/* getAudioListIndex
 * Given an element's id, find the index in audioList for the correct AudioObject */
function getAudioListIndex(id) {
  return componentDict[id];
}

/* clickPercent()
 * returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth */
function clickPercent(e, timeline, timelineWidth) {
  return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;
}

// getPosition
// Returns elements left position relative to top-left of viewport
function getPosition(el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
// GENERATE HTML FOR AUDIO ELEMENTS AND PLAYERS
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in settings */
function createAudioElements() {
  for (f in settings) {
    var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"" + settings[f].src + "\"></audio>";
    $("#" + settings[f].elementId).append(audioString);
  }
}

/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in settings */
function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (f in settings) {
    var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\">" +
      "</button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
    $("#" + settings[f].elementId).append(playerString);
  }
}

/* theDOMHasLoaded()
 * Execute when DOM is loaded */
function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
  // Generate HTML for audio elements and audio players
  createAudioElements();
  createAudioPlayers();

  // Populate Audio List
  populateAudioList();
  populateComponentDictionary();
}
```

```css
.audioplayer {
  width: 480px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 50px auto auto auto;
  border: solid;
}

.playbutton {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
}

.play {
  background: url('http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/img/play.png');
}

.pause {
  background: url('http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/img/pause.png');
}

.play,
.pause {
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.timeline {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.playhead {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>player 1</h3>
<div id="audio-player-1"></div>
<h3>player 2</h3>
<div id="audio-player-2"></div>
<h3>player 3</h3>
<div id="audio-player-3"></div>
```

Comment: YOU'RE MY LIFESAVER, THANK YOU. Finally!

One last question. How can I append a number of the file to `changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton play");` ? Just like you did with `function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (f in settings) {`

Thank you a lot, you're amazing, thank you.

Comment: At the first line of `AudioObject.prototype.play` function add 
`var fileIndex = parseInt(this.audio.id.replace("audio-", ""))`
and use this value in `changeClass` function.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the id for your new audio element,
see the working demo

```js
// Event listener for DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDOMHasLoaded, false);

// array of audio files (stored in a folder called music)
var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
  "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
  "interlude.mp3", // 2
  "scriptures.mp3" // 3
];

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Find and store audio info
///////////////////////////////////////////////

// array for AudioObjects
var audioList = [];
// components and the index for their AudioObject
var componentDict = {};
// store AudioObject that is currently playing
var playingAudio = null;
// store playhead id if one is being dragged
var onplayhead = null;

/* AudioObject Constructor */
function AudioObject(audio, duration) {
  this.audio = audio;
  this.id = audio.id;
  this.duration = duration;
}
/* bindAudioPlayer
 * Store audioplayer components in correct AudioObject
 * num identifes correct audioplayer
 */
AudioObject.prototype.bindAudioPlayer = function(num) {
  this.audioplayer = document.getElementById("audioplayer-" + num);
  this.playbutton = document.getElementById("playbutton-" + num);
  this.timeline = document.getElementById("timeline-" + num);
  this.playhead = document.getElementById("playhead-" + num);
  this.timelineWidth = this.timeline.offsetWidth - this.playhead.offsetWidth
}

/* addEventListeners() */
AudioObject.prototype.addEventListeners = function() {
  this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  this.audio.addEventListener("durationchange", AudioObject.prototype.durationChange, false);
  this.timeline.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick, false);
  this.playbutton.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay, false);
  // Makes playhead draggable 
  this.playhead.addEventListener('mousedown', AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

/* populateAudioList */
function populateAudioList() {
  var audioElements = document.getElementsByClassName("audio");
  for (i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++) {
    audioList.push(
      new AudioObject(audioElements[i], 0)
    );
    audioList[i].bindAudioPlayer(i);
    audioList[i].addEventListeners();
  }
}

/* populateComponentDictionary() 
 * {key=element id : value=index of audioList} */
function populateComponentDictionary() {
  for (i = 0; i < audioList.length; i++) {
    componentDict[audioList[i].audio.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playbutton.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].timeline.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playhead.id] = i;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Update Audio Player
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* durationChange
 * set duration for AudioObject */
AudioObject.prototype.durationChange = function() {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.duration = this.duration;
}

/* pressPlay() 
 * call play() for correct AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay = function() {
  var index = getAudioListIndex(this.id);
  audioList[index].play();
}

/* play() 
 * play or pause selected audio, if there is a song playing pause it
 */
AudioObject.prototype.play = function() {
  if (this == playingAudio) {
    playingAudio = null;
    this.audio.pause();
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton play");
  }
  // else check if playing audio exists and pause it, then start this
  else {
    if (playingAudio != null) {
      playingAudio.audio.pause();
      changeClass(playingAudio.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    }
    this.audio.play();
    playingAudio = this;
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton pause");
  }
}

/* timelineClick()
 * get timeline's AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick = function(event) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(event, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
}

/* mouseDown */
AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
  onplayhead = this.id;
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
  ao.audio.removeEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
}

/* mouseUp EventListener
 * getting input from all mouse clicks */
function mouseUp(e) {
  if (onplayhead != null) {
    var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
    // change current time
    ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(e, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
    ao.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  }
  onplayhead = null;
}

/* mousemove EventListener
 * Moves playhead as user drags */
AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead = function(e) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
  var newMargLeft = e.clientX - getPosition(ao.timeline);

  if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= ao.timelineWidth) {
    document.getElementById(onplayhead).style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft < 0) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft > ao.timelineWidth) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = ao.timelineWidth + "px";
  }
}

/* timeUpdate 
 * Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio 
 * this is the html audio element
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate = function() {
  // audio element's AudioObject
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  var playPercent = ao.timelineWidth * (ao.audio.currentTime / ao.duration);
  ao.playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
  // If song is over
  if (ao.audio.currentTime == ao.duration) {
    changeClass(ao.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    ao.audio.currentTime = 0;
    ao.audio.pause();
    playingAudio = null;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Utility Methods
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* changeClass 
 * overwrites element's class names */
function changeClass(element, newClasses) {
  element.className = newClasses;
}

/* getAudioListIndex
 * Given an element's id, find the index in audioList for the correct AudioObject */
function getAudioListIndex(id) {
  return componentDict[id];
}

/* clickPercent()
 * returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth */
function clickPercent(e, timeline, timelineWidth) {
  return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;
}

// getPosition
// Returns elements left position relative to top-left of viewport
function getPosition(el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
// GENERATE HTML FOR AUDIO ELEMENTS AND PLAYERS
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in files */
function createAudioElements() {
  for (f in files) {
    var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";
    $("#audio-players").append(audioString);
  }
}

/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in files */
function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (f in files) {
    var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  }
}

/* theDOMHasLoaded()
 * Execute when DOM is loaded */
function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
  // Generate HTML for audio elements and audio players
  createAudioElements();
  createAudioPlayers();

  // Populate Audio List
  populateAudioList();
  populateComponentDictionary();
}
```

```css
.audioplayer {
  width: 480px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 50px auto auto auto;
  border: solid;
}

.playbutton {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
}

.play {
  background: url('http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/img/play.png');
}

.pause {
  background: url('http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/img/pause.png');
}

.play,
.pause {
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.timeline {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.playhead {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audio-players"></div>
<audio id="audio-4" class="audio" preload="true">
    <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer-4" class="audioplayer">
  <button id="playbutton-4" class="play playbutton"></button>
  <div id="timeline-4" class="timeline">
    <div id="playhead-4" class="playhead"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing work, but I want to remove <div id="audio-players"></div> and instead use the full <div id="audioplayer-<id>"></div> element to insert a single player of my choice wherever I want.